# How to get text (Regular Expression) from QInputDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I want to know is there any way to get formatted text from `QInputDialog` that is I want  integer with comma as string from `Dialog`. Or can we apply regular expression to `QInputDialog` in `Text Mode`. If not please suggest better way to implement this scenario.

Thank you !

Comment: Why can't you use `QInputDialog::getDouble`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
QString result = QString::number(QInputDialog::getInt(this,"title","write"))+QString(",");//we enter for example 9
qDebug() << result; //we get "9,"
```

Or this

```
QString result = QString::number(QInputDialog::getDouble(this,"title","write")).replace(".",",");//we enter for example 3.3 (3,3 in the inputDialog)
qDebug() << result;//result 3,3 (not 3.3)
```

Comment: As per your second suggestion if i want more than two numbers then it will not more than 3 numbers. instead if i use QInputDialog::getText(), and apply regular expression for input But i don't know how to apply regular expression. Or its not possible for QInputDialog

Comment: @D'JayPatil with inputDialog you can't  do that. There are a few solutions. You can QInputDialog::getText() and format returned text(it is very simple, if you want, I can show you how it is works), but if you don't want this, if you want validate input, you should create your own small dialog with QLineEdit, set to this lineEdit QRegExpValidator - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexpvalidator.html (QLineEdit have setValidator method)  As you see, there is "short-time" solution and "long-time" solution.